# C# ASP.NET Google Checkout Notification Acknowledgment

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-checkout

Been working on this for a while and just can't get google to accept that I've done what they want so they keep sending me notifications for the same order. The documentation on this is available here:

[Google Notification Acknowledgement Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html#Responding_to_Notifications)

Here is my code on the page which recieves google notifcations:

```
 string serial = Request["serial-number"];

 // do my stuff

 StringBuilder responseXml = new StringBuilder();
 responseXml.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
 responseXml.Append("<notifiation-acknowledgment xmlns=\"http://checkout.google.com/schema/2/\" serial-number=\"");
 responseXml.Append(Request["serial-number"]);
 responseXml.Append("\" />");

 HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
 response.StatusCode = 200;
 response.ContentType = "text/xml";
 response.Write(responseXml.ToString());
```

Comment: You should really XML-escape the serial number as you append it. But I can't see anything wrong - maybe try ending with an AppendLine for a line feed? Or omitting the `<?xml`, or making sure there's a line break between that and the notification too?

Comment: Have you tried just using the GCheckout api for this? It encapsulates the google checkout calls into a library. http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html#googleCheckoutSampleCodeNETInstallCheckoutModule

Comment: 'Note: The .NET sample code distribution does not include classes or methods to process notifications or to send notification acknowledgments.'

Comment: I am using it just yeah, like I said above no examples for notifications and can't find any code to post the correct response.

Comment: Are you doing response.clear() and response.headers.clear() before this code? If not, this could cause problems if in a Page because of the default HTML generated. Also, try using response.end() after the last line to ensure your response stream is flushed to output.

Answer (score 4):

You have misspelt "notification-acknowledgment" as "notifiation-acknowledgment".

I would also suggest using [GCheckout](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html#googleCheckoutSampleCodeNETInstallCheckoutModule) as briercan said in the comments. If you use that, then all you would have to do is:

```
var ack = new GCheckout.AutoGen.NotificationAcknowledgment();
ack.serialnumber = serial;
Response.BinaryWrite(GCheckout.Util.EncodeHelper.Serialize(ack));
Response.StatusCode = 200;
```